# openSUSE Linux - Name based virtual host | Apache/2.4.33

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, opensuse

I desperately try to setup a name based virtual host for use in my local network, for hours.

This is my configuration, the path is correct

**/etc/apache2/vhosts.d/hausfux.conf**

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.40.44:80>

    ServerName hausfux.dev

    DocumentRoot "/srv/www/htdocs/hausfux/devLocal"
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/hausfux_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/hausfux_access.log common

</VirtualHost>
```

I informed myself [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/vhosts/name-based.html).

Then I added this line to my **/etc/hosts** file.

```
192.168.40.44        hausfux.dev
```

I also added the same line on my windows clients hosts file.

Then I restarted apache2 with `systemctl restart apache2`.

If I enter `http://hausfux.dev` in my windows clients browser, then it automatically changes to `https://hausfux.dev` and it fails.

If I try to open the project as I used to,with the full absolute link, e.g. `http://192.168.40.44/hausfux/devLocal` then I get Status Error Code 500 (server internal error) now. If I remove my virtual host and restart apache2 then the site works again.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: There are no errors in `/var/log/apache2/hausfux_error.log`

---

**Update**

If I use the following configuration, then it works if I type in the servers IP Adress in the browser at my windows client (http://192.168.40.44).

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName hausfux.dev

    DocumentRoot "/srv/www/htdocs/hausfux/devLocal"
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/hausfux_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/hausfux_access.log common

    <Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/hausfux/devLocal">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

But my goal is, to just enter a name, e.g. `http://hausfux.dev` instead of the ip address. Is this possible in OpenSUSE or should I use another OS, e.g. Ubuntu?

**Update:**

Response from pinging my DNS-Server:

> PING 192.168.40.20 (192.168.40.20) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from
>   192.168.40.20: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.126 ms 64 bytes from 192.168.40.20: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.149 ms

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I tried it. I even started the browser in inspector mode. Same problem.

Comment: try with a command line tool like curl or wget.
Additionally if you get redirected to the https part, create either a https part or find the reason why you are redirected, which is not in the config you show.
Look in the error/access logs.

Comment: If you ping the DNS name, do you get the desired IP address or something else?

Comment: @Tom, I added the response to my question

Comment: I said ping the DNS name, not the server.... if you do `ping hausfux.dev` do you see it pinging the IP address 192.168.40.44?

Comment: @Tom, I executed `ping hausfux.dev` the IP `192.168.40.44` is in the response.

Answer (score 0):

It works after I changed the virtual host name. I think I already used the same VHost name on my windows clients WAMP once and it is still in the config somewhere.

In WAMP you can suppress virtual hosts. Maybe I just supressed it instead of deleting it.