# .htaccess file is not getting loaded on Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, opensuse

I am using openSUSE Linux. I [failed to create a virtual host](https://serverfault.com/questions/936193/opensuse-linux-name-based-virtual-host-apache-2-4-33?noredirect=1#comment1214759_936193) so I put my project to the document root at `/srv/www/htdocs`.

**The .htaccess File is not getting loaded.**
My website does still load without an internal server error (status code 500) if I add garbage to the .htaccess file.

I added this block in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and restarted apache2, but the .htaccess file is still not producing a server error, so it was not loaded.

Comment: Are you sure you're sending the request to the right server? Do you see your requests coming in in the access log?

Comment: Did you check the error logs?

Comment: @Oldskool, yes it is the right server. There is new log content in `/var/log/apache2/access_log` if I reload the page.

Comment: @dkokmadis, there is no new content in `/var/log/apache2/error_log` if I reload the page. Even though there is garbage in the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our senior web-developer was able to solve it. We had to change `AllowOverride` to `All` in the file `/etc/apache2/default-server.conf`. The entry in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` had no effect, because `/etc/apache2/default-server.conf` has a higher priority.